# Memory Leak: Remaining elements in cache and data_user in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, svg

I create elements (some are SVG Tags, some are simple HTML) with ng-repeat. On changes of the data model - an object that is reset on arrival of new data - there are always elements left behind as detached DOM elements. They are held like this:

[image: Screenshot from Chrome Developer Tools]

The Elements are part of data_user which seems to be part of jquery. This problem occurs at several places on change of data. It seems that watchers are the problem, since they are keeping reference to their expression.

The elements are created e.g. like this:

```
.directive('svgGraphic', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var svgData = scope.model.getAttribute("svgGraphic");
            var svgDomElement =  $(svgData.svg);
            scope.layers = svgData.layers;

            svgDomElement.append('<svg-layer ng-repeat="layer in layers"></svg-layer>');
            element.append($compile(svgDomElement)(scope));

            scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
                scope.$$watchers = null;
                scope.$$listeners = null;
            })
        }
    };
}])
```

A workaround is to manually delete watchers and listeners as you can see above - what is no good solution I think!

When new data from the server arrives, it is set like this:

```
$scope.model = model;
$scope.$digest();
```

Is it a problem to just replace the model data?

Is there any idea how it can happen that angular does not remove listeners on old elements? Angular should delete all the watchers when ng-repeat receives new data and rebuilds all elements.

Comment: When a `$scope` is destroyed, the `$$watchers` and `$$listeners` should be emptied by the framework, so I'm wonder why your workaround is working!?

Comment: Totally true. But why are the watchers and listeners of the child scopes not cleaned up on $destroy as the parent scope is. I debugged the $destroy function, it it gets called only once for the parent scope! So only the watchers and listeners of the highest scope - not of the child scopes! - are removed. And this is exactly what causes our problems. So when will the child scopes empty their listeners and watchers?

Comment: I see. Could you show how the `svgGraphic` directive is used inside `ng-repeat`? The `ng-repeat` will call `$destroy()` for each removing item directly, so I guess there is something that introduce a new scope and make the `svgGraphic` has a different scope than the one from `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue. I created a Watcher Class, so then with the profiler I am able to count the Watcher instances. I saw that the instances continue increasing while I navigate the app, some of the instances are retained by the data_user cache :(.

Also I fixed the delete of childScopes watcher amd added some metadata to scopes, like a list of childScope.

Here is the angular code that I changed (only the functions that I changed). I hope this help you to found the error, I am still fighting with it :)

```
function $RootScopeProvider() {


 this.$get = ['$injector', '$exceptionHandler', '$parse', '$browser',
  function($injector, $exceptionHandler, $parse, $browser) {

 var watcherCount = 0;

function Watcher(listener, initWatchVal, get, watchExp, objectEquality, scope) {
  this.fn = isFunction(listener) ? listener : noop;
  this.last = initWatchVal;
  this.get = get;
  this.exp = watchExp;
  this.eq = !!objectEquality;
  this.scope = scope;
  this.id = watcherCount++;
}

Watcher.prototype = {
  constructor: Watcher
}

function Scope() {
  this.$id = nextUid();
  this.$$phase = this.$parent = this.$$watchers =
                 this.$$nextSibling = this.$$prevSibling =
                 this.$$childHead = this.$$childTail = null;
  this.$root = this;
  this.$$destroyed = false;
  this.$$listeners = {};
  this.$$listenerCount = {};
  this.$$isolateBindings = null;
  this.childsScopes = [];
}


Scope.prototype = {
  constructor: Scope,

  $new: function(isolate, parent) {
    var child;

    parent = parent || this;

    if (isolate) {
      child = new Scope();
      child.$root = this.$root;
    } else {
      // Only create a child scope class if somebody asks for one,
      // but cache it to allow the VM to optimize lookups.
      if (!this.$$ChildScope) {
        this.$$ChildScope = function ChildScope() {
          this.$$watchers = this.$$nextSibling =
              this.$$childHead = this.$$childTail = null;
          this.$$listeners = {};
          this.$$listenerCount = {};
          this.$id = nextUid();
          this.$$ChildScope = null;
        };
        this.$$ChildScope.prototype = this;
      }
      child = new this.$$ChildScope();
    }
    //window.scopes = window.scopes || {};
    //window.scopes[child.$id] = child;
    this.childsScopes.push(child);
    child.$parent = parent;
    child.$$prevSibling = parent.$$childTail;
    if (parent.$$childHead) {
      parent.$$childTail.$$nextSibling = child;
      parent.$$childTail = child;
    } else {
      parent.$$childHead = parent.$$childTail = child;
    }

    // When the new scope is not isolated or we inherit from `this`, and
    // the parent scope is destroyed, the property `$$destroyed` is inherited
    // prototypically. In all other cases, this property needs to be set
    // when the parent scope is destroyed.
    // The listener needs to be added after the parent is set
    if (isolate || parent != this) child.$on('$destroy', destroyChild);

    return child;

    function destroyChild() {
      child.$$destroyed = true;
      child.$$watchers = null;
      child.$$listeners = {};
      //child.$parent = null;
      child.$$nextSibling = null;
      child.$$childHead = null;
      child.$$childTail = null;
      child.$$prevSibling = null;
      child.$$listenerCount = {};
      if (child.$parent) {
        var index = child.$parent.childsScopes.indexOf(child);
        child.$parent.childsScopes.splice(index, 1);
      }

      console.log("Destroying childScope " + child.$id);

    }
  }

  $destroy: function() {
    // we can't destroy the root scope or a scope that has been already destroyed
    if (this.$$destroyed) return;
    var parent = this.$parent;
    console.log('Destroying Scope '+ this.$id);
    //delete window.scopes[this.$id];
    this.$broadcast('$destroy');
    this.$$destroyed = true;
    if (this === $rootScope) return;

    for (var eventName in this.$$listenerCount) {
      decrementListenerCount(this, this.$$listenerCount[eventName], eventName);
    }

    // sever all the references to parent scopes (after this cleanup, the current scope should
    // not be retained by any of our references and should be eligible for garbage collection)
    if (parent.$$childHead == this) parent.$$childHead = this.$$nextSibling;
    if (parent.$$childTail == this) parent.$$childTail = this.$$prevSibling;
    if (this.$$prevSibling) this.$$prevSibling.$$nextSibling = this.$$nextSibling;
    if (this.$$nextSibling) this.$$nextSibling.$$prevSibling = this.$$prevSibling;

    // Disable listeners, watchers and apply/digest methods
    this.$destroy = this.$digest = this.$apply = this.$evalAsync = this.$applyAsync = noop;
    this.$on = this.$watch = this.$watchGroup = function() { return noop; };
    this.$$listeners = {};

    // All of the code below is bogus code that works around V8's memory leak via optimized code
    // and inline caches.
    //
    // see:
    // - https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2073#c26
    // - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6794#issuecomment-38648909
    // - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1313#issuecomment-10378451

    this.$parent = this.$$nextSibling = this.$$prevSibling = this.$$childHead =
        this.$$childTail = this.$root = this.$$watchers = null;
  }


}];
}
```

Comment: Did you made a pull request with that changes? It solved the Detached DOM tree caused by data-> user_data from jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the cached SVG data.

## Directive Code

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module('ApplicationModule').directive("ngD3SvgRefreshDirective", ["$rootScope", function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            templateUrl: 'pages/directive/D3SvgMyRefereshDirective.html',
            scope: {
                svgData: "=svgData",
                reloadSvg: "=reloadSvg",
            },
            controller: function ($scope, $sce, $rootScope) {
                $scope.$watch('reloadSvg', function (nu, old) {
                    $scope.init();
                }, true);

                $scope.init = function () {
                    if ($scope.svgData && $scope.svgData.layoutURI) {
                        console.log("data");
                        if ($scope.svgData) {
                            // if data is present ###
                            var svgDiv = angular.element(document.querySelector('#svgDiv')).html("");
                            d3.xml($scope.svgData.layoutURI, "image/svg+xml", function (xml) {
                                svgDiv.append(xml.documentElement);
                                $scope.styleSVGPathsNaddCallBack();
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        // if data is not present ###
                        var svgDiv = null;
                        // selecting all the svg div which already present in browser ###
                        var svg = d3.select("svg");
                        svg.selectAll("*").remove();
                        console.log(svg);

                    }
                };
                $scope.styleSVGPathsNaddCallBack = function () {
                    var svgObject = d3.select('#svgDiv').select('svg');
                    svgObject.attr("width", "100.0%");
                    var objColor;
                    if (true) {
                        // your requirement logic

                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }]);
})();
```

### Controller

Controller and service combined. Data registery controller function.

```
$scope.dataRegisteryForMyDirective = function (data, dataFlag) {
    if (dataFlag) {

        var svgDataMaster = data;
        var svgData = {};
        $scope.svgData = {};
        svgData.layoutURI = data.layoutURI;
        $scope.svgData = angular.copy(svgDataMaster);

        $rootScope.reloadSvg = !$rootScope.reloadSvg;

    }
    else {
        // making svg data empty, so we can execute the else block of directive --> init()  and remove the cached data  ###
        $scope.svgData = {};
        $rootScope.reloadSvg = !$rootScope.reloadSvg;
    }
}
```

Service call and data registory call for directive:

```
$scope.loadSvgByNumber = function (inputNumber) {
    var d = inputNumber;
    myService.getData(d).then(function (resp) {


        if (resp.status == "FAILURE") {
            $scope.svgTempData = [];
            $scope.dataRegisteryForMyDirective(resp, false);
            // calling to dataRegisteryForMyDirective  with false flag 
        }
        else {
            $scope.dataRegisteryForMyDirective(resp, true);
            // calling to dataRegisteryForMyDirective with true flag
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Don't just post a code snipped. Explain it a bit so it is better to understand.

Comment: code is provided with comments